# Node js program gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, json, express

My Node js gives me the above TypeError. I'm trying to invoke a server called mathsServer that will receives a json string POSTED in Postan e.g

{
"tal": "10,343,24,345,22,23,233, 45, 200,500"
}

and it should add upp all the values in "tal" and diplay on the browser. Here is my code:

app.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = require("./router");

const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 3000

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("views" , "views");
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.use("/", router);


app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`The server is running at: http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require("./controllers/controller");

router.get("/", controller.renderHomePage)

router.post("/add", controller.renderSum)

router.get("/add",controller.renderSum)


module.exports = router
```

controller.js

```
  const mathServerModel = require("../../../mathServer/model/mathModel");
    const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
    
    exports.renderSum = (req, res) => {  
           
        mathServerModel.addera(req.body.tal)
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                res.send({data});
                res.render("post-tal", {
                    Sum: {data}        // A property called Sum to be displayed on the browser
                })
    
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        
    }
```

mathModel.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
exports.addera = async (tal) => {
    let strNumbersArr = tal.split(","); // ["10", "343", "24", ..., "233"]
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < strNumbersArr.length; i++) {
        let currentNumberStr = strNumbersArr[i];
        sum += Number(currentNumberStr); // convert current number string into a number
    }
    return sum;
    
}
```

Comment: Did you indicate "application/json" in Content-Type?

Comment: @Anatoly No, i haven't! Where should i indicate that in the code?

Comment: Right where you send a request from Postman or from a browser

Comment: Yes, in postman i changed to JSON, and i get the right result in the console, but when displaying on the browser is where i get the error. From browser? how?

Comment: Show a piece of code you use to send a request from a browser, please add it to your post

Comment: I have updated the post, check right from app.js, router.js, controller.js and model.js

Comment: I don't see any new code

Comment: Check above. You'll see the files. Refresh your browser.

Comment: Otherwise, you can access the project on this link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-n5f912POOlXm4jwtirqyY5gTIk7N031/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't indicate that you send data via a `form` HTML-tag. Is it right?

Comment: No, i used res.render()

Answer (score 0):

You have to call these middleware before you read any `req`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Just call these two middleware at your entrypoint file before `renderSum`
is executed, this will solve the issue

Comment: the problem now appears only when i refresh the browser so that the result can be displayed on the browser, that's when i get "Cannot read propert 'split()'". Otherwise the correct result is displayed on the terminal console.

Comment: Any comment? See the updated post with all the js files

Comment: When you refresh the browser same the `renderSum` is being executed here `router.get("/add",controller.renderSum)` but in this case as it is a get request and nothing is there in the `req.body` it again sends `undefined` to your `addera` function and throws the error. To solve this issue you will need some kind of Databse to save the sum

Comment: You also don't need the `bodyparser` middleware in both `controller.js` and `mathModel.js` files because this middleware is now executed at the entry point file that is the `app.js` before every request.

Comment: Ok. Instead of database, how about craeting a json file and store the sum, then render the sum on the browser?

Comment: So you mean that i do not need the router.get("/add", controller.renderSum)? All i wanted was the POST: then what i post is calculated and displayed on the browser localhost/add.

Comment: Just save it in a JSON from the post , then read the JSON in the get request

Comment: I actually did just that and it worked. Thanks.